# Span multiline equivalent

Tags: html

I want to style some text. I tried span but it only worked for the first line. but not for the second. Anyone have a solution? :)

HTML:

```
<div style="width:30%;">
<span style="margin:10px">Hey this is my span. Once it turns multi line the margin stops working</span>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JwcuZ/

I have also tried p But that just destroys my styling. I'm sure there is a simple solution for all this but my brain is playing tricks on me!

Comment: You have to provide **way** more information. How do you want to style the text? How does your HTML look like? What is the content? Create a demo and/or provide screenshots.

Comment: Basically i added a margin:10px; to the span. But because the text rolls over to the next line it doesnt add the margin to the second line. Sorry i didn't post this before.

Comment: That should not have any effect because `span` elements are not block elements and ignore the margin. I suggest you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JwcuZ/
See the difference between the top line and the others? Margin is applied to the first line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options:

- Instead of setting the margin of the `span` element, you can change the padding of the parent `div`:

  ```
  div {
      padding-left: 10px;
  }
  ```

  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/JwcuZ/3/)
- Use a `div` instead of a `span`: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/JwcuZ/4/)
- Set the `span`'s CSS `display` property to `block` or `inline-block`: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/JwcuZ/5/)

Comment: Thankyou! I used a div instead :D

Comment: You're welcome :) Apparently I was wrong about `span`'s ignoring the `margin`. Apologies for that.